# How do i get the file content after clicking "show more"

Tags: php, curl

I want to scan the user likes on a favorites page on Facebook

http://www.facebook.com/username/favorites

I'm using cURL to get the file content with PHP but I'm stacked with getting all of the data in the page, because you need to click a jquery button for this.

Is there a way to get the data after clicking the  "**Show Other Pages**" button?

Comment: Use a Web developer Tool (like Firebug) to figure out which request is made after the click.

Answer (score 0):

As ynh said, use a Web Dev tool. I did so and found that the link sends an AJAX call that is visible in the source of the page. Try logging in and reading the source... it should look like this...

```
<a rel="async" ajaxify="THE_CALL_GOES_HERE" href="#">Show Other Pages</a>
```

(I removed my data for obvious reasons)

If you can emulate this, you should be able to get the information you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "emulate" ? this is the hard part i did not understood.  i want to inject more links to this div, but i dont know how facebook sends the data... Json, Post ?  this is my problem. i will appreciated your help, my knowledge in php and in English is not good as you can see. TY